# How to detect whether a Git server supports shallow cloning?

Tags: git, github, github-enterprise

Some Git servers or hosting services (apparently GitHub Enterprise) are not supporting shallow clones, instead they simply stall when a request like the following is sent:

```
git clone --depth 1 https://server/user/repo.git
```

Is there a way to detect whether the server supports shallow cloning or not? Is there a Git or CURL command that I can send to the server to find out whether it supports shallow cloning or not?

I've found a reference to [Git Protocol Capabilities](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/protocol-capabilities.txt), is this what I need to look for? How can I get a hold of the server's capabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The smart protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols) does some advertisement

```
ssh -x git@server "git-receive-pack 'simplegit-progit.git'"
005bca82a6dff817ec66f4437202690a93763949 refs/heads/master report-status \
    delete-refs side-band-64k quiet ofs-delta \
    agent=git/2:2.1.1+github-607-gfba4028 delete-refs
```

> The git-receive-pack command immediately responds with one line for each reference it currently has – in this case, just the master branch and its SHA-1.
>   The first line also has a list of the server’s capabilities (here, report-status, delete-refs, and some others, including the client identifier).

The git remote helpers have [options related to the shallow capability](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/gitremote-helpers.txt#L448-L449), but it is not clear they would be advertised the same way as in the ssh command above.

[git 1.6.6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b31222cfb7f2fcdc5b3d76ce5fcebf6ff1929826#diff-fc5caba3aac86fb0b240c2bf0a095874R129) updated the packfile transfer protocol, including a "[Reference Discovery](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cf8a8c6bd53c43e29cb735eb7934ffc996475d77/Documentation/technical/pack-protocol.txt#L128-L144)" section:

> When the client initially connects the server will immediately respond
>   with a listing of each reference it has (all branches and tags) along
>   with the object name that each reference currently points to.

```
$ echo -e -n "0039git-upload-pack /schacon/gitbook.git\0host=example.com\0" |
nc -v example.com 9418
00887217a7c7e582c46cec22a130adf4b9d7d950fba0 HEAD\0multi_ack thin-pack
side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow no-progress include-tag
00441d3fcd5ced445d1abc402225c0b8a1299641f497 refs/heads/integration
003f7217a7c7e582c46cec22a130adf4b9d7d950fba0 refs/heads/master
003cb88d2441cac0977faf98efc80305012112238d9d refs/tags/v0.9
003c525128480b96c89e6418b1e40909bf6c5b2d580f refs/tags/v1.0
003fe92df48743b7bc7d26bcaabfddde0a1e20cae47c refs/tags/v1.0^{}
0000
```

---

These days (Git 2.23, Q3 2019, 4 years later), a `git fetch -v -v` would be enough to show any supported capabilities.

See [commit 0e04297](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e042971011956be86a59fb3b5e0dbf3a127fae5), [commit 5a88583](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a88583b0b241c335b4baf2ccd9b04bc1650efcb), [commit 0778b29](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0778b2931c8d561b02046a80870af7c9f4d14d52) (20 Jun 2019) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b49d337](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b49d337bfbdd431697161244ff7b2241d9887c9f), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `fetch-pack`: print server version at the top in `-v -v`
>
> Before the previous patch, the server version is printed after all the
>   "`Server supports`" lines.
>   The previous one puts the version in the middle of "Server supports" group.
>
> Instead of moving it to the bottom, I move it to the top.
>   Version may stand out more at the top as we will have even more debug out after
>   capabilities.
>
> ### `fetch-pack`: print all relevant supported capabilities with `-v -v`
>
> When we check if some capability is supported, we do print something in
>   verbose mode.
>   **Some capabilities are not printed though (and it made me
>   think it's not supported; I was more used to `GIT_TRACE_PACKET`) so let's
>   print them all**.
>
> It's a bit more code. And one could argue for printing all supported
>   capabilities the server sends us. But I think it's still valuable this
>   way because we see the capabilities that the client cares about.

Comment: I've read a lot about the smart protocol, but I'm not sure this helps. I've tried to run the SSH `git-receive-pack` command against GitHub (not Enterprise), and it doesn't send back the `shallow` capability, yet GitHub supports shallow cloning without any problems.

Comment: I agree. I just meant to give some clues, to start looking where and how shallow clone is managed on the server side.

Comment: Thanks - this seems to be a rather complex topic, and I'm completely stumped why GitHub Enterprise doesn't seem to support this cleanly.

Comment: As seen in your other question today, you have a lot of questions to ask to github support ;)

Comment: Indeed - it's a real nightmare :-)